# content-type not supported in web service error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

when i run my client service by giving my web service reference to it. it doesn't play video and download it instead it gives error like this:

**Error**

```
The content type video/mp4 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' ftypmp42mp42mp41isomavc1"�moovlmvhd�x\R�x\RX:�@*iods���O����������ttrak\tkhd�x\R�x\R:�@@�$edtselst:��mdia mdhd�x\R�x\RwU�6hdlrvideL-SMASH Video Handler�minfvmhd$dinfdrefurl Nstbl�stsd�avc1@�HH AVC Coding��5avcCd��gd��AA���`h��,���paspsttswctts_D'.

 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.    Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type video/mp4 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' ftypmp42mp42mp41isomavc1"�moovlmvhd�x\R�x\RX:�@*iods���O����������ttrak\tkhd�x\R�x\R:�@@�$edtselst:��mdia mdhd�x\R�x\RwU�6hdlrvideL-SMASH Video Handler�minfvmhd$dinfdrefurl Nstbl�stsd�avc1@�HH AVC Coding��5avcCd��gd��AA���`h��,���paspsttswctts_D'.
```

here is my service code which is invoking perfectly.

**ASMX**

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<UploadFile> GetUploadedFiles()
    {
        using (Database1Entities1 SampleDb = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            return SampleDb.UploadFiles.ToList();
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void ViewData(int File_ID)
    {
        using (Database1Entities1 SampleDb = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            var File = SampleDb.UploadFiles.Where(f => f.Id.Equals(File_ID)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (File != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = File.ContentType;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File.Content);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


            }}

    }


    } }
```

**Client Code**

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
{
    ServiceReference1.VideoWebServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.VideoWebServiceSoapClient();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            DataGridView.DataSource = client.GetUploadedFiles();
            DataGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DataGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
        {
            int File_ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            client.ViewData(File_ID);

        }

    }
```

Can any one please solve this problem.. ??

Comment: You can't really return binary data froma SOAP web service unless you converted it to a base64 encoded string or similar as a SOAP service returns XML. If you just want to return a binary stream use a handler (ashx) or a web api controller instead.

Comment: sir i am new to web services i have no idea. could you please guide me properly how to do this.?